# X11 freezes and responds to no input?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, xorg

Recently, I've began to notice that my Ubuntu installation is having some serious problems with X. On occasion, my system will lock up, and X will no longer update the screen. I can still do things in the background (?), but I can't see them.

However, this is remedied by either a reboot, or by switching to TTY1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then switching back.

My system runs an Optimus (NVIDIA + Intel) setup, with the below (trimmed) `lspci` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 745M] (rev a1)
```

I have `nvidia-prime` and driver version 352.30.

My graphics environment is Cinnamon with Docky on the side.

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux hostname 3.16.0-50-generic #66~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 17:05:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Try X.org (i think that's X11, forgive me.) or TinyX.